# Can you connect client to client via web sockets without touching the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, websocket

I don't quite know how to search this in google:

- "client to client websocket connections"
- "browser to browser websockets"
- "websockets without a server"

Haha, is there a way for someone on a webpage in the browser to communicate directly to another person on a web page in the browser, without touching the server?

I am very familiar with [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io), but that requires all clients `emit` messages to the server, which can `broadcast` them to the other connected clients.  I am not familiar with the details of web sockets though, so maybe there's a way to communicate without sending messages through the server.

Is this possible?  I just want to know the scope of web socket functionality, the limits you can take them too, etc.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Not without having one of the client's behave like a server at least.

Comment: can a client behave like a server?

Comment: If this is a personal project and you just want to do this to connect to your own computer or something, yes, by setting up a local server (like XAMPP) and getting a static IP Address (or using DynDNS)

Comment: Maybe this works?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162470/communication-among-two-to-client-side-sessions-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i do a client to client (browsers) socket connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864550/how-can-i-do-a-client-to-client-browsers-socket-connection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, you have to have the server in the middle.

Answer (score 13):

Not Web Sockets, but four years later and now we've got browser-to-browser communication!
http://www.webrtc.org/

There are JS libraries built around it to make it easier (e.g. https://simplewebrtc.com/). However, it does still require a server to orchestrate connections.

I know this question is ancient, but it showed up in Google when I searched so it likely will for others!

Answer (score 1):

For an application to accept connections, it has to have a server port open and listening for incoming requests. You cannot have a server socket exposed from a browser. I dont know if you can expose a server socket from within an applet. But even if you could, you would need to know the IP address of the other client for establishing a peer to peer connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically when you `broadcast`, the client `emits` to the server, the server broadcasts to everyone. I don't think with the current architecture of the web peer to peer connections like this is possible.

But it is possible that a client send a message to server specifying another client ID, and the server sending it to the other clients using [sessions](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/).

Answer (score 0):

The moment you have a client listening for websockets (which you have to do in other to communicate), it becomes a server.