# Communication among two to client side sessions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be a crazy question, just trying my luck.
We are building a HTML5 application, we have a need for colloboration between two users the same way as in Google Docs two users can simultaniously edit a document and they can see each others changes.

In our case the document is never stored at server side and we do not want to host a service at server side for synchronization between two clients.

The users will be on same WiFi network.

Is there any way through two client side user sessions can communicate with each other?
We want to avoid installing anything on client machine except of running our app in browser.

Thanks,
Navneet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
You might find this interesting: http://www.webrtc.org/

This project is actually supported by Google, Mozilla and Opera so could have a future

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, I understand that WebRTC is still in Beta and available for only Chrome Beta. We are looking for something which can run cross browser.