# emits from client must be called again in server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a problem with understanding how socket.io and node.js works.

I tried few examples with emitting messages and it worked. What I don't understand is emitting from clients.

I use emit in client, for example: `socket.emit('custom_event');`, but it doesn't work in other clients unless I add something like this in my server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('custom_event', function() {
    socket.emit('custom_event');
  });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to always add definition on server side for something that client should be emitting to other clients?

Comment: if you want to send message to all the connected clients then use `socket.broadcast.emit`

Comment: I want to send that message to clients with only `socket.emit('custom_event')` called from client. Without defining 'custom_event' on server side. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible, socketio need the server logic between your clients.

You can do:

`socket.broadcast.emit`

Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it.

---

`io.sockets.emit`

Emits to all, (inc the socket that starts the action.)

But allways from the server

[Can you connect client to client via web sockets without touching the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018544/can-you-connect-client-to-client-via-web-sockets-without-touching-the-server)

Comment: Ok, I understand that I need a server logic. But is it possible for example to always catch all client emit events and emit them to all other clients without specifying emit name on server side? I would like to omit modifying server code each time I want to add new emit event from client.

Comment: I found the solution for me here: https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-wildcard Thanks for help and additional info!