# Status change shown in HTML page

Tags: html

what technology may I use to update the status (in term of data) of a dynamic page without user interaction and only through TCP messages?

Comment: Can you add a bit more context and detail and what technology you are using on server side?

Comment: May be this helps: [How can I communicate over TCP sockets from JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307539/how-can-i-communicate-over-tcp-sockets-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need JavaScript on the client side (such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)) making [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) calls to a server-side application.  It will return [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json)-formatted data, which you can then [use to update the page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) on the client side.

I think anything which relies on direct direct TCP communication is going to be very fragile from one user's browser to another – that's not something which browsers typically facilitate, due to security concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
If you have a component that changes frequently it's state as I can represent this status via a web page?

Comment: Well, you can represent this status using a web application.  In the web page, you would have jQuery doing a poll to the web app at certain intervals -- every thirty seconds, for example.  The web app would then reply, and the JavaScript could do what it needs to do with the data.