# Connect via JavaScript to a C# TCP-Listener

Tags: c#, javascript, tcplistener

i've already looked up in the web, but can't find any solution for it.

Is it possible to connect to a TCP-Listener with JavaScript?

I don't look for socket.io or node.js - cause I don't want to use an external programm like they are.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: I wanna connect to a TCPListener which is written in C#

Comment: What language it's written in is pretty arbitrary.  Could just as easily be any other .NET language.

Comment: What do you with this comment?

Comment: Just that you shouldn't tag things with a specific language unless the question actually pertains to the language.  In this case you only care about sending data to a [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx), which is a framework class, it could just as easily be F# on the other end processing data.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307539/how-can-i-communicate-over-tcp-sockets-from-javascript

Comment: Errm. I just need an example for JavaScript which connects to a C# TCP-Lister. The problem isn't related to C#...